# RHEL8:RabbitMQ enable plugin - File access error

Tags: rabbitmq, rhel

I have installed rabbitmq rpm package in RHEL 8. But when I try to enable any of the plugins I get the following error. After the install the plugin file in `/etc/rabbitmq` permission is `0600 root:rabbitmq`. I changed it to 0777 but after the rabbitmq starts it changes to 0600 and when I try to enable any plugin, I get the following error.

```
# sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_prometheus
Enabling plugins on node rabbit@server:
rabbitmq_prometheus
The following plugins have been configured:
  rabbitmq_management
  rabbitmq_management_agent
  rabbitmq_mqtt
  rabbitmq_prometheus
  rabbitmq_web_dispatch
Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@server...
Stack trace:

** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: {:error, {:cannot_read_enabled_plugins_file, ~c"/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins", :eacces}}
    (rabbitmqctl 3.12.1) lib/rabbitmq/cli/plugins/plugins_helpers.ex:112: RabbitMQ.CLI.Plugins.Helpers.update_enabled_plugins/4
    (rabbitmqctl 3.12.1) lib/rabbitmq/cli/plugins/commands/enable_command.ex:127: anonymous fn/6 in RabbitMQ.CLI.Plugins.Commands.EnableCommand.do_run/2
    (elixir 1.15.4) lib/stream.ex:1530: anonymous fn/2 in Stream.iterate/2
    (elixir 1.15.4) lib/stream.ex:1757: Stream.do_unfold/4
    (elixir 1.15.4) lib/stream.ex:1828: Enumerable.Stream.do_each/4
    (elixir 1.15.4) lib/stream.ex:1052: Stream.do_transform_inner_enum/7
    (elixir 1.15.4) lib/stream.ex:1828: Enumerable.Stream.do_each/4
    (elixir 1.15.4) lib/enum.ex:2564: Enum.reduce_while/3

{:case_clause, {:error, {:cannot_read_enabled_plugins_file, ~c"/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins", :eacces}}}"
```

I tried changing the permission , user/groups to rabbitmq , running as sudo but still getting the same error. The rabbitmq service file has umask 0027 defined , modifying it to 0022 had no effect. Any advice on how to fix this.